# jQuery / php refresh CAPTCHA

Tags: php, jquery, captcha

I'm using a simple captcha in my contact us page. I would like to add a refresh function using javascript / jQuery.
The function that makes the captcha image is in a separate file.
When the page loads the CAPTCHA works well but I can't make the refresh.
My code is:

```
<head>
...
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#reload').click(function(){
            $("#captcha").load("functions/captcha.php"); // function that creates the NEW CAPTCHA
            $("#captcha").attr("src", "images/captcha.jpg?"+(new Date()).getTime());
        });
    });

...
</head>
<body>
<?php 
  require(functions/captcha.php);
 ?>

  // form
  ...
  <label for="captcha_code">ENTER CAPTCHA</label>
    <img src="images/captcha.jpg" id="captcha" /> 
      <a id='reload'>Refresh now</a>
        <input type="text" name="captcha_code" value="captcha_code">
  ...
```

I really would appreciate your help.
Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You should wait before "functions/captcha.php" fully loads.

Try this example:

```
<div id="loader"></div> <!-- hide this div by css -->
$('#reload').click(function() {
     $("#loader").load("functions/captcha.php",  function() {
          $("#captcha").attr("src", "images/captcha.jpg?refr="+(new Date()).getTime());
     }); 
});
```

But isn't it better to create `functions/captcha.php` that outputs an image and just refresh the `src` parameter?

Comment: Thank you Tomasz but it still doesn't work. You are right but firstly I would like to figure out how to create a new one.